# array_push to non-associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

The code below generates an associative array (key=>value), how can I have a non-associative array (e.g. just keys)? e.g. `array('1','2','3','4','5');`

```
$join_have = array();
$join_need = array();
array_push($join_have,$row2['id']);
array_push($join_need,$row3['id']);
```

I'm trying to construct two arrays to compare the database autoincrement id's for a JOIN table. The JOIN table is one of three (it allows unlimited number of associations instead of statically adding columns in the tables).

The point is to determine what JOIN table id's I have to keep, what I will DELETE and what I will INSERT for id's.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. this will give you an array with starting index `0`. what is it that you want?

Comment: Edited, I just want to compare have/need arrays to determine what join table (three tables, a join allows unlimited use of the other two) id's I keep, remove or need to add.

Comment: please provide a concrete example

Comment: Still do **not** understand what u need....

Comment: Updated, hope this clarifies.

Comment: Do you only want the arrays keys? If so, just use `array_keys()`.

Comment: @John: I still have no idea what you're asking.  Did you even try your example?  It makes an array with numeric keys.  Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/FwL7Y).  All arrays in PHP are "associative", they all have keys and values.  Unless you set they key to be a string, it will be numeric (starting at 0).

Comment: Could you clarify the question? PHP arrays by definition always have both a key and value.  Might also help if you show the value of $row2, the values you are getting now in $join_need, and what you'd like to see in $join_need instead.

Comment: As far as I understand the code, it generates a non-associative array. If you want just keys use array_keys().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays in php always have keys and values since it's very definition is an ordered map.

For example

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Would have the following key, value pairs.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

I think what you're asking is how do you set the keys in an array instead of the value.

You would simply do.

```
$join_have = array();
$join_have [ $row2['id'] ] = '';
```

This would still give you a key, value pair but you would be setting the key.

Comment: `array_flip` on the original array will also do the job.

Comment: Yes, but why not construct it how you want in the first place, instead of constructing it then flipping it ?

Comment: I agree in the context of the question, but in general it seems like code smell.

Comment: warning: `array_flip` will destroy arrays with same values.